# gunicorn: ERROR (no such file) nginx + gunicorn + supervisor

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I deploy my django project with gunicorn, nginx, supervisord. 
I installed a gunicorn in virtualenv, added in INSTALL_APPS. 
The command `./manage.py run_gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8999` works:

```
2012-12-04 12:27:33 [21917] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.16.1
2012-12-04 12:27:33 [21917] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8999 (21917)
2012-12-04 12:27:33 [21917] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2012-12-04 12:27:33 [22208] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22208
```

For nginx I edited nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 111111111:80;
    server_name my_site.pro; 

    access_log /home/user/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /home/user/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/user/my_project/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /home/user/my_project/media/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8999;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    }
}
```

After that I restarted nginx.

supervisord.conf:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor-my_project.sock  
chmod=0700                
chown=user:user

[supervisord]
logfile=/home/user/logs/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        
logfile_backups=10           
loglevel=info                
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord-my_project.pid
nodaemon=false              
minfds=1024                  
minprocs=200 

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor-my_project.sock 

[program:gunicorn]
command=/home/user/bin/manage run_gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:8999 -t 300 --max-   requests=1000
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=60
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/user/gunicorn.log
```

I ran `bin/supervisorctl start all`. But I got:

```
gunicorn: ERROR (no such file)
```

What the file is missing? How can I deploy my project?

Answer (score 14):

For future searchers, I had this problem and the issue was that I needed to provide a full path to the Gunicorn binary. For whatever reason, even with the PATH= environment variable specified supervisor couldn't find the binary. Once I /full_path/gunicorn it worked. (Maybe there's a way to do this correctly with environment variables)

Comment: In our case we had missed a `supervisorctl reread` after updating configs, so the `start` command was looking for a binary that had been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using virtualenv you must set the environment to the PATH used by it in supervisord.conf.

Try this:

```
[program:gunicorn]
command=/home/user/bin/manage run_gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:8999 -t 300 --max-requests=1000
environment=PATH="/home/user/bin/"
...
```

This is assuming `/home/user/bin/` is the path to your virtualenv.

Comment: I edited supervisord.conf and added: `command=/home/user/my_project/bin/gunicorn_django -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:9999 -t 300 --max-requests=1000
directory=/home/user/my_project/stratatech/stratatech/ And after that bin/supevisorctl start all, gunicorn was started. But my site dont open on address in server_name (nginx.conf). Why?

Comment: In nginx.conf change listen 111111111: 80; to listen: 80; then restart nginx.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, actually I found out there is no gunicorn installed in my virtual environment.

Do

```
pip install gunicorn==<version_number>
```

Comment: More suited to be a comment as it is a suggestion to install `gunicorn` and then try!

Answer (score 0):

I switched from installing supervisor using apt to using pip. This changed the path of supervisor and pidproxy from /usr/bin to /usr/local/bin/.   I use pidproxy in my supervisor gunicorn.conf.

So just switching the supervisor install method meant not finding "pidproxy" and generated the message "gunicorn: ERROR (no such file)".

The poor error message could be referring to something other than gunicorn.

> command=/usr/local/bin/pidproxy /var/run/gunicorn.pid /gunicorn.sh